# PHP string comparison with different random encoding

Tags: php, encoding

I have a problem when I compare two strings coming from different sources (I have no control of the source code) <=> an encoding problem:

- `$a` -> from HTML page
- `$b` -> from XML

E.g.:

```
string(11) "Jean-Paul"
string(13) "Jeanâ€Paul"
```

I find for this example that the second one has not been already found *- so I insert it in DB -*, and I display twice the same entry on the html page.
Browsers display them both the same (Jean-Paul, Jean-Paul).
Source code is:

> `Jean-Paul, Jean&#8208;Paul`

Is there a way to convert the texts in order to find the same result?
I tried `mb_convert_encoding()`, `utf8_encode()`, `htmlentities()` but the problem is that it's encoding the `'â€'`.

**I need a general solution** which converts any text to its "displayed value", so that I can compare both with the final values.

Thanks in advance.

Bast

---

EDIT:

An example of the source: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/pcmr.12142/abstract

Here I get `Jean&#x2010;Paul`, which I compare with Jean-Paul

---

EDIT2:

I think that the crawlers/parsers analyze and/or interpret the content they get from different websites, right?

So I am wondering if a function 'getCharacterStandardRepresentation()' which return a "generic" character doesn't exist...

It can "simply" lists all the possible characters representations and render a 'standard' character.

It could be interesting even for people who want to compare any file with the content from their DB.

Comment: Does you string contains any special characters? anytime?

Comment: what are the sources webpages or documentfiles?

Comment: Sorry, there _cannot_ exist a "general solution" for this. How should? If you do not know the encoding of the strings you receive (why not?), then how do you want to re-encode them in a sense that makes sense? It is impossible to detect what encoding a string is in, as opposed to what some people claim. It _is_ possible to prove that certain texts can _not_ be of a certain encoding, but that's it. All functions promising an "auto detection" make a horrible job, guessing is more precise. So without knowing your source encoding the old rule applies: garbage in => garbage out

Comment: @arkascha you're absolutely right, but I think he has a good chance, because if it's a whole webpage, he can check for the given encoding. And as far as I know, It's the same for XML. If encoding is given, of course :)

Comment: Could you tell us where exactly the strings come from (what kind of sources) and if you know the encoding or not.

Comment: @swidmann That is what my "why not?" referred to :-)

Comment: @swidmann XML is easy: it's defined as having UTF-8 by default, unless explicitly changed in the XML declaration. What I worry about in the OP's example is how they manage to display a string like `"Jean&#8208;Paul"` as `"Jeanâ€Paul"`. That's some serious misencoding going on.

Comment: @arkascha, I cannot know the encoding of the string because it can come from different websites. I am parsing metadata from different website I am interested on. So I can get a dash '-' with several different encoding. So if I understand properly, no way to convert the "garbage" of really good websites?

Comment: If you make an http request you get headers up front. One of those typically specifies the encoding. Certainly that might be wrong, and it surprisingly often is, but you should _use_ that specified encoding. That is all the information you have.

Comment: @arkascha, yes I know :) just wanted to point out, If he receives a well formatted document (HTML, XML) the encoding should be given and he can check against it

Comment: @Bast, almost every website has also an given encoding tag like `<meta charset="utf-8">`. you said you are parsing meta data? It is a meta tag

Comment: @Bast if you get `&#8208;` from a website, that's what it is, there has to be no guessing what encoding it's in. This is a character with codepoint U+2010, HYPHEN, no matter the encoding. No matter if it's HTML or XML. If your program translates this to anything else than a hyphen, it's a bug in your program, not a wrong setting. We'll need to see the source code.

Comment: @MrLister, they don't display "Jeanâ€Paul"... that's what I'm getting from the metadata. e.g.: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/pcmr.12142/abstract  -- I did not want to provide a source because otherwise I did not want  a specific answer.

Comment: @MrLister, yes you're right. that **might** be an ongoing problem :)

Comment: @Bast Hm... is your problem that the name Jean-Paul occurs multiple times on the page, sometimes with a normal dash (ASCII minus) and sometimes with a U+2010 hyphen? And you want those two different characters treated the same? That wasn't entirely clear in the question.

Comment: @MrLister, I am getting Jean-Paul from an XML (remote source), but get the U+2010 from the metadata. So I cannot compare both of them, so I treat them as different.

Comment: @arkascha, BTW: I thought there could be a general solution because browsers manage to display them both the same. so I thought maybe there is a way to render the same "code equivalent" from 2 different (but equivalent) symbols...

Comment: @Bast Sure there is, provided some information about the encoding exist. If that is missing, then the browser has to guess, if it is wrong, then the browser will display nonsense. You can do the same, but you have to check what encoding is specified. How else would you know what you actually have in your string? And what is the problem with that?

Comment: So there seems to be a solution...The answer should be: 1. detect encoding of string FROM METADATA. 2. convert into the same encoding. 3. Compare strings.  I will try this, and then post a reply if it's working. Thanks

Comment: You cannot convert these two characters into the same encoding, because they are different characters. This has nothing to do with encoding! They may look almost the same in most fonts, but that doesn't matter; they're still different! The best you can do is provide a lookup table for _fallback characters_ and perform a replace on each string you read.

Comment: @MrLister Ok, yes this makes more sense... I am surprised that nobody created such a function which lists all the possible character representations and render a "generic" character...How does the other crawlers / parser do? Don't they analyze/interpret content from different websites?

Answer (score 0):

For the XML value you can use (after first edit where you get `Jean&#x2010;Paul`)

`html_entity_decode($xml_value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')`

to convert it and then compare it with HTML value.

Hope it solves your problem.